# activeadmin habtm better example for uniqueness case

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

Am able to manage habtm as per follow, and I wanted a better way for this

I have habtm between User and Tag on Rails 3, aa 0.5.1
Tag name is uniq

```
  f.input :tags, :label => 'Assign existing tag'                             
  # this above allows to select from existing tags, but cannot allow to create one

  f.has_many :tags, :label => 'Add new tags, modify existings' do |ff|
    ff.input :name
    ff.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean
  end
  # this above allows to create new one but not allow to specify existing one
  # if we specify existing one, uniqueness wont let create this one, neither existing get used
  # and throws validation error
```

any hints?

Adding my models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  scope :tagged_with, lambda {|tags| joins(:tags).where("tags.name" => tags)}
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  validates :name, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
end
```

Comment: post your model too to see your associations and the first thing why you cant use the select rather than input in the form?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
f.label => 'Assign existing tag'
f.select :tags, Tag.all.map{|t| [t.tag_name, t.id]}, {:prompt => "Select Tag name" }
```

## this above allows to select from existing tags, don't have option to create one

For the Second thing add this line in the model,

```
validates :tags, :uniqueness => {:scope => :tag_name}
```

## here the :tag_name is your name of the fieldname. This throw an error if the tag name already exists when you create a duplicate.

It's just an idea as per your question. This won't be your exact answer because your specification is not enough to give you the exact answer.